# When is a module a tensor product of two given modules?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I am currently writing down interesting facts about short exact sequences. One interesting fact is that we can find out, when a given $R$-module $M_2$ is the direct sum of two other $R$-modules $M_1,M_3$, which is the case precisely when there is a *split short exact sequence* of the form
$$0 \longrightarrow M_1 \longrightarrow M_2 \longrightarrow M_3 \longrightarrow 0.$$

I was wondering, whether this can be used to deduce that for vector spaces we have $\dim_K (V \otimes_K W) = \dim_K(V) \cdot \dim_K(W)$, but noticed that the issue (in finding a suitable short exact sequence) lies in having $\cdot$ instead of $+$. So I wondered

> Is there a general criterion for when an $R$-module $M_2$ is the $R$-tensor-product of two given $R$-modules $M_1,M_3$? Or even harder: Is there a general calculus of *generalized tensor products* of modules just like short exact sequences generalize direct sums?

In the following I want to collect some thoughts on this:

- For vector spaces the first question has a simple criterion: $V_2$ can be written as $V_1 \otimes_K V_3$ precisely if $\dim_K(V_2) = \dim_K(V_1) \cdot \dim_K(V_3)$. This relies on the fact that every vector space is free (admits a basis) and should generalize verbatim to free $R$-modules (maybe one needs the ring to have IBN). However for non-free modules the question remains very much open (to me at least).
- A problem which comes to mind is that the tensor product $M \otimes_R N$ doesn't come with canonical maps of the form $M \rightarrow M \otimes_R N$ or $M \otimes_R N \rightarrow M$. However, given an element $n\in N$ there is a canonical map $R \rightarrow N$ and hence by functoriality a map $M \cong M \otimes_R R \rightarrow M \otimes_R N$. So maybe a starting point is to consider *pointed modules*, by which I mean objects of the slice category $R/\mathsf{Mod}_R$.
- There is a very similar question of when, given a ring homomorphism $f:R \rightarrow S$, an $S$-module $N$ is of the form $M \otimes_R S$ for some $R$-module $M$. This can be answered in specific cases *faithfully flat descent*. This is itself a special case of *monadic descent*. But this is all I know yet and moreover I feel like we are **not** in a monadic situation e.g. due to issues with conservativity.

This is all I got until now. Thank you for reading this and thank you in advance for any comments and answers!

Comment: Every module is tensor product of itself with the ring. So are you asking whether it is true given all the three modules?

Comment: Yes exactly. All three modules are part of the question.

Comment: The class of finitely-generated modules with operations $\otimes$ and $\oplus$, perhaps modulo free modules, has been studied. Some "K-theory", other homological stuff. An easy case is f.g. modules over Dedekind rings: see "Steinitz' theorem". There is a clear answer...

Comment: @paulgarrett thanks for the comment! You are right that (under mild assumptions) my question boils down to a question of an element of $K(R)$ being the product of two others, but in my limited experience with K-groups this might be highly nontrivial as well… Regarding Steinitz‘ theorem I don’t quite see yet, how this answers my question, as it seems to involve decomposition of modules into sums (and some products of ideals, but this is not the same as tensor products of ideals). Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @PrudiiArca, well, among other true things that can be said (!), the tensor products of ideals in a Dedekind domain form a group, literally, without any fancier interpretation.  E.g., an ideal can be expressed as a tensor product  in more than one way as a tensor product of ideals. (For global fields the ideal class group is finite...) Steinitz' theorem would say that f.g. modules with tensor product modulo free is exactly that ideal class group. Is this helping? Yes, in general I think there are no simple answers to such, although the questions can be formalized in such (or fancier) terms. :)

Comment: @PrudiiArca, and, to be clear, the "product" of ideals inside a Dedekind ring _is_ naturally isomorphic to their tensor product over that ring.

Comment: Why is "... when there is a universal bilinear map $M_1 \times M_3 \to M_2$" not an answer to your question?

Comment: @paulgarrett $K$-theory mods out a lot of stuff which is not the case here.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, oh, yes, I realize, but it might be interesting to solve a "simpler" problem first, etc.

Comment: There won't be an answer in the language of (additive) categories, since $\mathbf{Mod}_R$ has multiple non-equivalent symmetric monoidal structures.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Of cause having the correct universal property is one way of showing things to be isomorphic. One could say the same thing about direct sum decompositions, but nevertheless having split short exact sequences is a very nice and convenient tool…

Comment: @paulgarrett thanks for the clarification. Its been a while since I’ve seen Dedekind domains and invertible ideals. Im not even sure whether I learned anything interesting about the ideal class group… Regarding the tensor product of ideals being the product of ideals I think I was too cautious. I thought there was an issue with the tensor product being noncommutative (which for ideals of the ground ring is nonsense). I recently fell into a trap like this, but it might be in sheaf theory and not plain algebra, and maybe there wasn’t even an issue there. Anyway thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don’t quite understand your comment on the additive category perspective. My question is about the tensor product, which is given by the adjoint to the internal hom. So we have very much information and a concrete construction at hand. Of cause one might ask, under which conditions an object of a monoidal category is the monoidal product / tensor of two given others, but this feels more complicated to me than my question about the tensor product of modules…

Comment: @paulgarrett the issue with $I \otimes_R J$ as opposed to $I \cdot J$ is that it is not clear why the equation $i\otimes j = j \otimes i$ should hold in $I \otimes_R J$, while $ij = ji \in I \cdot J$ certainly holds. Maybe I am missing something obvious, but I don’t see why your identification holds…

Comment: @PrudiiArca, well, I guess I'm thinking that $I\otimes J$ is isomorphic to $J\otimes I$... That's all.

Comment: @paulgarrett my point is that I don’t see a reason why the multiplication map $I \otimes_R J \rightarrow I\cdot J \subseteq R$ should be injective, rendering $I \otimes J$ and $I \cdot J$ as different $R$-modules… You are of cause right that the tensor product is symmetric, but I don’t think this is the same problem…